# React locomotive scroll метод on()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как в react-locomotive-scroll вызвать метод on()?

```
const ref = useRef(null);

 const options = {
    smooth: true,
    lerp: 0.08,
    table: {
      smooth: true
    },
    smartPhone: {
      smooth: true
    },
  }

    <LocomotiveScrollProvider options={options} containerRef={ref}>
       <div className={demoFour.demo_four} data-scroll-container ref={ref}>
         <div className={demoFour.demo_four__container}>
            <section className={demoFour.home} data-scroll-section=""></section>
          </div>
       </div>
    </LocomotiveScrollProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно импортировать useScroll из библиотеки

```
import { useScroll } from 'react-locomotive-scroll'
```

Получив можете получить ссылку на объект scrollController, а затем вызвать метод on() для этого объекта.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const { scrollController } = useScroll()

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollController.on('call', () => {
      // Do something when the call event is fired
    })
  }, [scrollController])

  return (...)
}
```

Можно еще использовать состояние и useState для установки состояния при запуске события и использовать это состояние в своем компоненте.

```
const ExampleComponent = () => {
  const { scrollController } = useScroll()
  const [eventFired, setEventFired] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollController.on('call', () => {
      setEventFired(true);
    })
  }, [scrollController])

  return (
    <div>
      {eventFired ? <p>Event fired!</p> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: В библиотеке изменилось название useScroll на useLocomotiveScroll, ну не суть.  Я получаю ошибку при вызове scrollController.on('call'). Ошибка не описывается, просто The above error occurred in the <DemoFour> component:

Comment: Прошу прощения, действительно в новых версиях библиотеки название изменилось. Попробуй для метода `scrollController.on('call')`  использовать `const scroll = useLocomotiveScroll(); scroll.addEventListener('call', () => { ... })`

Comment: К сожалению это тоже не помогло :(

Comment: А react-locomotive-scroll последнюю версию используешь? И еще на console не проверил значения scroll объекта, возвращаемого useLocomotiveScroll, чтобы убедиться, что оно правильно определено?

Comment: Версия у меня "react-content-loader": "^6.2.0". На счет обьекта scroll. Мне он консолит null, даже если я в useEffect смотрю

Comment: Тык у тебя  "react-content-loader", должно быт "react-locomotive-scroll".   useLocomotiveScroll и метод addEventListener, о которых я упоминал ранее, недоступны в библиотеке «react-content-loader».

Comment: Сорри не то скопировал "react-locomotive-scroll": "^0.2.2",

Comment: useEffect для получения объекта прокрутки  возвращает значение null, думаю из за того что useEffect запускается после первого рендеринга, поэтому может случиться так, что объект прокрутки еще не доступен, когда он запускается. Вместо использования useEffect попробуй использовать useLayoutEffect. useLayoutEffect запускается синхронно после того, как браузер нарисовал макет, чтобы объект прокрутки стал доступен.

Comment: для useLayoutEffect для получения объекта прокрутки:` import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';const ExampleComponent = () => {const scroll = useLayoutEffect(() => {console.log(scroll);}, []);return (...)}`

Comment: Точно также null :(